# How can I create a RecyclerView in Kotlin that can be smoothly scrolled both horizontally and vertically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I was able to create a structure like the one seen in the following video, but it shows strange behavior towards the bottom right and top right corner

[DEMO GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trsNz.gif)

**fragment_standings.xml**

```
...

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    ...


....
....


<!--Table-->
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/standings_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_standings_table_row" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
...
```

**StandingsFragment.kt**

```
...
private fun initRecyclerView(standings: List<Standing>) {
        binding.standingsRecyclerView.apply {
            //layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter = StandingsRVAdapter(
                standings = standings,
                onStandingClicked = onStandingClicked()
            )
        }
    }
...
```

I tried the codes I shared and I was able to create a scrolling feature that behaves oddly as seen in the video, but I couldn't achieve the scrolling feature that behaves smoothly

Comment: Not in Kotlin (but can be used in Kotlin) and not a recyclerview but with extra features like fixed headers (which can be useful for the type of table you show) https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout or if you want a recyclerview without zoom and some issues and not maintained https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I believe this problem can be solved without using dependency.